# CXF 2.x and Jboss AS 7.1.1

Tags: java, json, cxf, jboss7.x

I'm having a hard time implementing a REST web service using Apache CXF 2.x. I have a strict requirement to use JBoss AS 7.1.1 Final, which comes equipped with CXF 2.4.6. I have installed   JBossWS 4.1.1: Apache CXF integration stack which upgrades the CXF version to 2.6.4. I'm using Eclipse Kepler SR1 in which I had to install "JBossAS Tools" so I could set JBoss AS 7.1.1 as my project runtime. The following are the different classes I'm using as well as my web.xml:

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>CXF</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>RESTServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet.CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jaxrs.serviceClasses</param-name>
            <param-value>
                webservice.StudentServiceImpl
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>StudentServiceImpl</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

**Student.java**

```
package pojo;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "student")
public class Student {

    private String name;
    private String lName;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getlName() {
        return lName;
    }

    public void setlName(String lName) {
        this.lName = lName;
    }

}
```

**StudentService**

```
package webservice;

import pojo.Student;

public interface StudentService {

public Student getStudent(String firstName,String lastName);
}
```

**StudentServiceImpl.java**

```
package webservice;

import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import pojo.Student;

@Path("StudentService")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService{

    @POST
    @Path("/student/{firstName}/{lastName}")
    public Student getStudent(@PathParam("firstName") String firstName,@PathParam("lastName") String lastName) {

     Student student = new Student();
     student.setName(firstName);
     student.setlName(lastName);

     return student;

    }

}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is having a REST webservice that returns a complex object (Student in this case) as a JSON String. Keep in mind that I've configured the CXF endpoint in Eclipse with a CXFServlet rather than Spring. Another note is that I'm using Apache CXF 2.7.6 as my CXF runtime since I couldn't find a valid link to download CXF 2.6.4. My context root is called "CXF" but when I browse to the URL `http://localhost:8080/CXF/`, I get error HTTP error 404.
What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**
I just noticed that upon deployment, the following exception is being thrown:

```
17:51:26,489 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-1) Failed to define class org.apache.cxf.wsn.jms.JmsPublisher in Module "deployment.CXF.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/apache/cxf/wsn/jms/JmsPublisher (Module "deployment.CXF.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:396)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:243)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:517)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:327)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:391)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:243)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:517)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentClassIndex.classIndex(DeploymentClassIndex.java:54)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:63) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:55) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/activemq/advisory/ConsumerListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:327)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:391)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq.advisory.ConsumerListener from [Module "deployment.CXF.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 41 more

17:51:26,563 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-1) Failed to define class org.apache.cxf.wsn.services.JaxwsPublisher in Module "deployment.CXF.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/apache/cxf/wsn/services/JaxwsPublisher (Module "deployment.CXF.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:396)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:243)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:517)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentClassIndex.classIndex(DeploymentClassIndex.java:54)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:63) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:55) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/wsn/jms/JmsPublisher
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:327)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:391)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cxf.wsn.jms.JmsPublisher from [Module "deployment.CXF.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 26 more

17:51:26,690 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-1) Failed to define class org.apache.cxf.wsn.jms.JmsPublisher in Module "deployment.CXF.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/apache/cxf/wsn/jms/JmsPublisher (Module "deployment.CXF.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:396) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:243) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:517) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2300) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1745) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:57) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:58)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:70)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:55)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/activemq/advisory/ConsumerListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:327) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:391) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq.advisory.ConsumerListener from [Module "deployment.CXF.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    ... 30 more

17:51:26,757 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."CXF.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."CXF.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "CXF.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error getting reflective information for class org.apache.cxf.wsn.services.JaxwsNotificationBroker with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.CXF.war:main" from Service Module Loader
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:58)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:70)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:55)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/wsn/jms/JmsPublisher
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2300) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1745) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:57) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cxf.wsn.jms.JmsPublisher from [Module "deployment.CXF.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 15 more

17:51:26,811 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "CXF.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"CXF.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"CXF.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"CXF.war\""}}
17:51:27,096 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-10) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment CXF.war in 285ms
17:51:27,100 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."CXF.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."CXF.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "CXF.war"

17:51:27,107 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"CXF.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"CXF.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"CXF.war\""}}}}
```

Comment: I made a bit of progress. I resolved the class not found exception by adding the activemq library in my project's lib folder. Now I'm getting this exception:
 org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011054: Could not find default constructor for class org.apache.cxf.wsn.client.Publisher

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had a similar problem trying to run a Web Service on JBoss AS 7.1.1 Final + jbossws-cxf-4.0.2.GA. The way we solved the problem was adding the CXF jar´s from the Jboss module as a variable through the build path configuration on Eclipse. This way the libs you will be able to accomplish the "compile dependency" suggested by @mike4263. Here is a good tutorial on how to do it: http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29.

Comment: Do you happen to use Maven? I have a big fat `pom.xml`, does that mean I have to tweak it for this to work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the other version of CXF from your package.  There seems to be some impedance mismatch between the container version and the bundled version.  Your application should be relying upon the version deployed with JBoss.  This is a fairly common mistake, and it means you aren't leveraging the pre-configured version and will likely hit other integration/support problems

You can configure the dependency to be a "compile dependency", and ensure that it is not bundled intot he output WAR file.

Answer (score 0):

I has same issue. I resolved as below.

1. Remove below tag in standalone.xml(on jboos)

   ```
   <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:1.2">
       <modify-wsdl-address>true</modify-wsdl-address>
       <wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host>
       <endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/>
       <endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config">
           <pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers" protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_MTOM">
               <handler name="RecordingHandler" class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler"/>
           </pre-handler-chain>
       </endpoint-config>
   </subsystem>
   ```

2.If do not want Remove them. Find Lib "cxf-services-wsn-core-2.7.1.jar"  to your project.

This solution working to me.